# Are any of the 'interslavic' constructed languages actually intelligible with any natural slavic languages?

Tags: slavic-languages, mutual-intelligibility, interslavic

Long ago, I thought about learning Slovianski (one of a family of auxlangs meant for speakers of Slavic languages), purely because I thought it may give me the ability to understand (to some extent) multiple Slavic languages. I never did so, though. Note that Slovianski has been merged with other 'interslavic' conlangs into a single conlang project. I think the new conlang is just called 'Interslavic'. Also note, if you do try to look up one of these conlangs, most of the sites are being made by the guy who made Slovio, who constantly makes websites lampooning other Interslavic projects (most of them teach a slight modification of his auxlang Slovio, which is really just Esperanto with a Russian-based vocabulary).

I would like a more professional opinion on the usefulness of learning this language. I don't know much about the Slavic languages, other than their phoneme inventories and their huge number of inflections.

Would knowing one of these Interslavic conlangs actually let you understand some natural Slavic languages, or is it only really useful (or as useful as an Auxlang attempt can be) for native speakers of Slavic languages?

Comment: "I would like a more professional opinion on the usefulness of learning this language."  My professional opinion is that it's not useless but not very useful for the effort.  Hard to learn without real speakers and real content.  If and when significant numbers of native Slavic speakers themselves use it it will be different.  But SE answers are not a place for opinions.

Comment: If you want something obscure then Old Church Slavonic.  If you want to maximise coverage then learn 1 West Slavic, 1 South Slavic and 1 East Slavic.  Don't learn Russian first because it is far from the average then you will never learn anything else.  Slovak or Ruthenian are the most average.

Comment: Related question on [conlang.se] (unfortunately no answers yet): https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/784/is-there-any-evidence-that-learning-a-zonal-slavic-conlang-can-help-conversing-w

Answer (score 3):

Slavic languages are famous for their degree of mutual intelligibility, and there are ongoing scientific studies on this question. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any studies throwing constructed languages like Slovianski in the mix of studied languages.

You may be interested in the project [INCOMSLAV](http://www.sfb1102.uni-saarland.de/?page_id=296) and their publications; they use only existing Slavic languages and some artificial mixtures of them.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning Interslavic.
https://youtu.be/NztgXMLwv4A
http://steen.free.fr/interslavic/

I am not a professional linguist, but I must note from my own experience, and from the review of a large number of Slavic commentaries, that this language is 90% -100% automatically understandable for any intelligent Slav who is fully educated and knowledgeable in his native language(!).

The more acute problem for Interslavic, as I understand it, isn't this, but the presentation of more complex concepts and the use of complex language.
However, as you can see on the site, it also outlines much more complex concepts than some village talk about the "брюхо".
In addition, this project continues to evolve, as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find current information about the inter-Slavic project and there are also publications from professional journals for download. These are texts tested by international conferences and there is also information on statistical research, how the language is accepted and what it might be useful for.

http://interslavic-language.org/

There is also a good site on wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interslavic